# Process SOAPAction with CXF

Tags: soap, cxf, apache-camel

I'm trying to figure out how to process a SOAP request, where the SOAPAction is specified in message header, but NOT in the message body. Following is an example request that I need to process.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://soap.afis.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
         <String>12</String>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The SOAPAction is in the header of the above request, as:

> SOAPAction: "urn:process"

Following is a request that works. Note the "process" element (AKA the SOAPAction).

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://soap.afis.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:process>
         <String>12</String>
      </soap:process>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the CXF endpoint:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="afisProcessEndpoint"
                     address="/wildcat"
                     serviceClass="com.afis.CCHEndpointImpl"/>
```

Here is the implementation:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "com.CCHEndpoint")
public class CCHEndpointImpl implements CCHEndpoint {
    @Override
    @WebMethod(operationName = "process", action = "urn:process")
    public String process(@WebParam(partName = "String", name = "String") String string) {
        return "sd";
    }
}
```

Here is the interface:

```
@WebService
public interface CCHEndpoint {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "process", action = "urn:process")
    public String process(@WebParam(partName = "String", name = "String")String string);
}
```

If I submit a request without the process element in the XML (but in the SOAP header), I get the following:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unexpected wrapper element String found.   Expected {http://soap.afis.com/}process.</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Note that with Axis2, I'm able to process such requests, because the services.xml maps actions to operations for us, but I'm unable to use Axis2 for this project. I need an equivalent mechanism with CXF. I feel that extra configuration in cxfEndpoint, or maybe an annotation, but I can not find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<soap:process>` element in the request really has nothing to do with the action.   That's a wrapper element.  Per JAX-WS spec, by default, services are created in "wrapped" mode where there is a wrapper element put as the direct child of the soap Body.   If you don't want that and just want the operation parameters directly, then you would need to add the `@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)` annotation onto the interface.